# Apply a word-boundary anchor to all tokens in a single regex

Tags: javascript, regex, word-boundary

Say I have a list of tokens I want to match in a string: tok1, tok2, tok3, and so on...

I want a word-boundary to be applied to all of them in a single regex, but without copy-pasting `\b` everytime. Here is what I'm trying to avoid:

```
/\btok1\b|\btok2\b|\btok3\b|\btok4\b|\btok5\b/g
```

I tried:

```
/\b(str1|str2|str3|str4|str5)\b/g
```

But it doesn't work as expected with javascript `.replace()` method.

Is there another way to apply a word-boundary anchor to all tokens in a single regex ?

**--- EDIT: ---**

Example of regex I'm trying to factorize:

```
/\bjohn\b|\bjack\b|\bheather\b/g
```

Expected result :

```
john     //match
jack     //match
heather  //match
wheather //not match
hijack   //not match
johnny   //not match
```

Comment: I don't see a problem with both approaches. What should be the end result?

Comment: Do you mean like [`\btok\d\b`](https://regex101.com/r/whNeZ1/1)?

Comment: I edited my question to clarify the regex I'm trying to factorize and the expected result.

Comment: What does not  work as expected with javascript .replace() method. Try it in a non capturing group `\b(?:john|jack|heather)\b`

Comment: works like a charm, thank you! Could you please post your solution (with a brief explanation as why it's working) as an answer so I can mark it as accepted ?

Comment: You did the same thing in your question. Didn't you? @Lau

Comment: I used a capturing group. The non-capturing group actually solved my problem, but I still have to understand exactly why and how

Comment: No, same code works with capturing groups. @Lau

Comment: I'd ask you to show us your earlier JS code you used to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use a non capturing group and add the tokens.

Use the `/g` global flag to match all occurrences. Then use [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) to replace the matches with your replacement value.

[`\b(?:john|jack|heather)\b`](https://regex101.com/r/AfcdpT/1)

```js
var str = "john, jack, heather, wheather, hijack, johnny";
var res = str.replace(/\b(?:john|jack|heather)\b/g, "test");
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Do you have any idea about OP's own regex?

Comment: This code also works with a capturing group, but you could do without it. Reading the comments, maybe he can tell us?